# Laravel 9 Tailwindcss always must npm run dev after code change

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I have installed Tailwindcss on Laravel 9 and the problem is that whatever I change in the code in the blade.php files, Tailwindcss does not work. Only when I run npm run dev and refresh the page, the effect is visible.
Why after each code change in laravel blade files I have to do npm run dev otherwise tailwindcss does not work as if it does not recognize its classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `npm run watch` to watch for changes and recompile your styles and scripts when you save.

> The npm run watch command will continue running in your terminal and
> watch all relevant CSS and JavaScript files for changes. Webpack will
> automatically recompile your assets when it detects a change to one of these files:

Read more about it here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#watching-assets-for-changes